# C pointer is not at the same address

Tags: c, json, pointers

I am running into an issue with a pointer being a different address than I expected (I know I have syntax wrong, I just can't see it, and yes I am new to C).

I am using the json library called `jansson` and I wrote a simple static wrapper to convert an incoming string to json, but also do some error checking.

```
json_t *jsonRoot;
char jsonString[1024];

static bool jsonLoad(char *string, json_t *root){
    json_error_t jsonError;
    root = json_loads(string, 0, &jsonError);
    // Then some error checking is done, and no errors are found
    if(!root)
    {
      return false;
    }
    if(!json_is_object(root)
    {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void main(){
    printf("Incoming string is %s\n", jsonString);
    if(!jsonLoad(jsonString, jsonRoot)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    json_t *id;
    id = json_object_get(jsonRoot, "id");
    if(!json_is_string(id))
    {
        // Getting into here
        printf("Jansson Error: not a string\n");
    }
}
```

What I am seeing for sure, using breakpoints, is that my json object gets loaded just fine, but when I get back to the context of main to then use jsonRoot, it is pointing to a different address entirely.

Comment: You are only modifying a local variable inside `jsonLoad`, so the global variable `root` is completely unaffected.

Comment: I had a typo, the very first line should have been `jsonRoot` not `root`

Comment: The exact same problem remains, as does the misunderstanding of how function arguments work in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you ar putting the pointer to jsonRoot into the local variable root. If you passed in the address of jsonRoot and put the result into the indirection, then you would see it. See the change in the definition of jsonLoad and the call to it.

```
json_t *jsonRoot;
char jsonString[1024];

static bool jsonLoad(char *string, json_t **root){
    json_error_t jsonError;
    *root = json_loads(string, 0, &jsonError);
    // Then some error checking is done, and no errors are found
    if(!(*root))
    {
      return false;
    }
    if(!json_is_object(*root))
    {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void main(){
    printf("Incoming string is %s\n", jsonString);
    if(!jsonLoad(jsonString, &jsonRoot)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    json_t *id;
    id = json_object_get(jsonRoot, "id");
    if(!json_is_string(id))
    {
        // Getting into here
        printf("Jansson Error: not a string\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this bad practice to use a double pointer? Is it an indication that the design is bad?

Comment: @BarryBones41 It is a pattern that is used in a lot of C code, when returning data from a function you either have to use the return value or a pointer to the output location. Often people use the return value for error codes so the actual data gets exported through those output pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted sabbahillel's answer but also rewrote this to be a bit more to my liking and probably more logical.

```
json_t *jsonRoot;
char jsonString[1024];

static bool *jsonLoad(char *string){
    json_error_t jsonError;
    json_t *root;
    root = json_loads(string, 0, &jsonError);
    if(!(root))
    {
      return NULL;
    }
    if(!json_is_object(root))
    {
      return NULL;
    }
    return root;
}

void main(){
    printf("Incoming string is %s\n", jsonString);
    jsonRoot = jsonLoad(jsonString);
    if(jsonRoot == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    json_t *id;
    id = json_object_get(jsonRoot, "id");
    if(!json_is_string(id))
    {
        printf("Jansson Error: not a string\n");
    }
}
```